# Traversing a tree structure using recursion

Tags: data-structures

I am dealing with one table on the database. The columns are: id, name, parent_id, hasChildren. (parent_id would be an id on the table. if parent_id is null, the record *is* a parent.)

What would be the best way to loop through this data so I can add it to a list like:

`- item1` 
`- item2` 
`>> item 2.1` 
`>>>> item 2.1.1` 
`>> item 2.2` 
`- item3`

etc etc.

**edit** - when i say "list" i mean like a listbox

**edit2** - woops, yes, list needs to be sorted by parent record alphabetically. i'm using mssql.

Comment: is the Tree sorted?
does the order need to be kept to the list?

Comment: What DB are you using? Oracle for example supports tree dependency queries directly ...

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 allows you to define hierarchies in a table:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx
- [Question about SQL Server HierarchyID depth-first performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714224/question-about-sql-server-hierarchyid-depth-first-performance)

You could also use a recursive CTE:

- [Determine the hierarchy of records in a SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578521/determine-the-hierarchy-of-records-in-a-sql-database)