# sorting hierarchical datas in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, hierarchical-data, hierarchicaldatatemplate

My database structure is:

```
Table Name: Category
Columns: CategoryID | CategoryName | ParentID
```

I want to list all categories by their children and their childrens' children also. I'm using `WITH` for finding all levels in MS SQL, but how can I show that in ASP.NET? I tried many different things about that but nothing has worked for me. I found `Treeview` in some websites but I didn't use that.

I also have another question about hierarchical data: when I search for a product that is connected to child and list the parent categories how can I show the child's products?

Comment: Maybe showing what you have already tried would be a good place to start.  Also, this isn't a Classic ASP question - I've removed that from the tag list.

Answer (score 0):

can't you do this by FK_relations between datas? anyways what query or table structure you have will help us move on to the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of what is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338519/traversing-a-tree-structure-using-recursion and here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/447343/Traverse-a-MSSQL-table-without-using-CURSOR

Comment: for showing this data, you can use simple ul-li and call the data in <%%> in code blocks

Comment: i didnt do that its not working. sorting good but when want to do likes this kind of side menu

Comment: can you share some example of what you are actually trying to pull